# Making Flash work on Firefox Quantum 57 (PPAPI, NPAPI, pepper), Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, firefox, flash, adobe, firefox-extensions

In this post I look rather for clarification than technical solution (the problem is already solved, see below).

I just upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04 and installed a fresh Firefox, which happened to be Quantum 57.0.3 (64 bit). Flash didn't work, thus I installed `flashplugin-installer`, which has in its description:

> The Adobe Flash Player plugin will work with a range of web-browsers >including, limited to:
>    * Firefox

Unfortunately it didn't help. What helped was the installation of `browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash` instead. The description of the latter package states:

> The main goal of the project is to get PPAPI (Chrome) plugins
>   working in Firefox (and any other web-browser supporting NPAPI plugins

I wanted to understand why the former package didn't work, thus I started to read and found out [here](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/52.0/releasenotes/#changed) that Firefox since ver 52 does not support NPAPI plugins, **except for** Adobe Flash. Therefore, it seemed that having `adobe-flashplugin` installed should be enough and one does not need to deal with the NPAPI/PPAPI issues. Indeed, after I removed `browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash` and sticked to `adobe-flashplugin`, everything worked fine. Thus, I suspect that the crux was in one of the packages required by `browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash`, not that package itself.

Would the conclusion be that Firefox in 16.04 ships without Flash support, even when `adobe-flashplugin` is present (I wonder why)? 
If so, some users might bump at this problem, just as I did.

Comment: The official Flash Player package (see the linked question) for Ubuntu uses the newer PPAPI in Firefox and other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot make sense of your observations that `adobe-flashplugin` works without `browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash` but `flashplugin-installer` does not. `adobe-flashplugin` and `flashplugin-installer` provide the very same NPAPI plugin. Maybe you simply forgot to restart your browser or something...

[This page](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html) provides a concise summary on the topic, including an attempt to explain when `browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash` may be a useful.

Comment: Indeed, the fact I used two different packages is only confusing, that was not supposed to be my main point. It was supposed to be that after I installed and removed browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash, flash started to work, thus I thought that there was an indispensable package in its dependencies, which 'enabled' the adobe flash player (regardless to the package it came from).

Comment: @Maciek: Ok. I still think it was merely a coincidence. Installing either `flashplugin-installer` or `adobe-flashplugin` and restarting Firefox ought to be sufficient.